# Was there a historical requirement to announce altitude, temperature, etc?

Tags: safety, pilots, regulations

It is a common experience of flying on commercial flights that pilots announce certain flying conditions, including altitude and speed.

It has been previously asked on Aviation SE [why pilots announce the cruising altitude of flights](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2555/why-do-pilots-announce-the-cruising-altitude-of-a-flight).  The answer there suggested there was "no real reason".

On Quora, it was asked similarly [why pilots frequently announce altitude, outside temperature, and speed](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-pilots-tell-us-the-planes-altitude-outside-temperature-and-speed-Does-it-matter).  The first answer there suggested it was previously a historical requirement; however, the answer does not provide a reference to these requirements.

Has there been historically, or is there now, a requirement in any major jurisdiction (FAA, EASA, etc.) for the pilot (or flight crew) of a commercial flight to announce altitude, outside temperature, speed, wind, or weather conditions?  If so, what was/is the specific text of the requirement?

Comment: I know of no requirement to make such announcements, but I often did for the simple reason that I thought some pax might be interested.

Comment: I would guess that if there was a historical requirement it would be a company requirement (e.g. Pan Am, etc.), not a regulatory requirement.

Comment: @terry I always appreciate trivia like that as a passenger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do pilots announce the cruising altitude of a flight?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2555/why-do-pilots-announce-the-cruising-altitude-of-a-flight)

Comment: @Notts90: That is the first link in my question, and my question is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

As this may be most common among airlines, this is not a requirement whatsoever administered by the FAA or any other aviation governing body. This is more so considered a tradition usually when the plane reaches cruise or is about to land. No such modern airline or any airline in the past has required this to be announced to its passengers.

Comment: "No such airline" is a pretty broad statement. Is that all currently flying airlines? Is it all airlines that have ever flown? Do you have anything to back that up? I'm not saying you're wrong, some supporting evidence would make your interesting answer (which is in line with the comments on the OP) much stronger.

Comment: I did some research @FreeMan and no result seems to state required announcements that the crew has to give to the passengers relating to what the question other than safety concerns such as in emergencies. I also fixed my answer a bit.